# SCCM -Meaing of “microsoft windows nt workstation 10.0 (tablet edition)”

Tags: windows-10, sccm, sccm-2012

Most of our computers registered in SCCM report "microsoft windows nt workstation 10.0 (tablet edition)". We only have a small number of tablet computers, the majority are laptops.

Please can someone advise what this means and what it implies as we are worried that we have done something wrong with the imaging process. We use a custom image build that is based of the installation media that you get from the 365 portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not really a special edition of windows, it used to be in times of xp but nowadays this just means the service "Tablet PC Input Service" is running. Why this also "renames" the OS Caption I don't know but it is something I noticed as well.
It does however not mean that there is anything missing or wrong with your computers, the only thing where this could lead to a problem is if you use some wmi query for gpos e.g. and wrote them like `"name = '%10.0'"` or something similar because without a trailing wildcard the query will fail.

As to how this got activated it is a little bit hard to say but we have some Laptops that are conventional form factor but still have a touch panel which could be one reason. There are also certain accessories like styluses or drawing pads that might lead to this service being active. That being said I have seen systems with this active where I could not find any plausible reason so it seems not always given that we are able to understand how the mechanism works.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, that makes sense as our laptops have touch screens.